# Can't Embed HTTPS Image in SVG and after open with Illustrator

Tags: image, svg, https, embedding, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to embed an HTTPS image in SVG with the `image` tag, aiming to open it in Illustrator. This is my current code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500">
<image xlink:href="https://placehold.co/50x50" height="50" width="50"/>
</svg>
```

Here a jsfiddle code:
https://jsfiddle.net/didofiddle/53jz8cgv/

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // Create an SVG element
  var svg = new Blob(["<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='50' height='50'><image href='https://placehold.co/50x50' height='50' width='50'/></svg>"], {
    type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
  });

  // Create URL representing the SVG
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(svg);

  // Load SVG into an image element
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    // Once image is loaded, draw it onto the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  }

  // Start loading the image
  img.src = url;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

The image doesn't load in the browser or in Illustrator. I also tried base64 encoding for the image, which works in the browser and with other design programs like Sketch, but not with Illustrator.

My goal is to export the SVG with the embedded images and open it correctly in Illustrator. But when I use base64 images, Illustrator doesn't handle it properly, and when I use `href` with the image link, I can't see the image in the SVG I'm trying to export.

How can I embed an HTTPS image in SVG that Illustrator can handle?

Comment: The snippet seems to display just fine to me in a browser. You don't seem to have a programming question though, just a question about how to use Illustrator, or whether Illustrator supports this.

Comment: Related question and answer: https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/illustrator-does-not-support-my-svg-file-that-contains-svg-image-elements/td-p/9651571

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I think it's a wise decision by applications like Illustrator not to fetch remote sources.

Consider the consequences if a graphics application were to download external files: it would introduce a lot of **security implications**. Also, an svg file that is supposed to work as an editable file should better be **self-contained**.

However, you could try to write a javaScript helper – similar to your jsFiddle example:

- fetch external sources
- convert their content to a data URL
- replace remote href/src attributes with the data URLs
- in case of remote svg files: Adobe Illustrator apparently doesn't accept vector data in a data URL. So instead we can convert the external svg to a `<symbol>` and replace the `<image>` with a `<use>` element referencing a symbol

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg');

makeSVGStandalone(svg);

async function makeSVGStandalone(svg) {
  const ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  const nsXlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
  const svgimages = svg.querySelectorAll("image");

  for (let i = 0; i < svgimages.length; i++) {
    let img = svgimages[i];
    let src = img.getAttributeNS(nsXlink, "href");
    let blob = await (await fetch(src)).blob();

    // if type is svg - embed as symbol with use element
    if (blob.type === "image/svg+xml") {
      let svgMarkup = await blob.text();
      // convert svg to symbol
      let symbol_id = "symbol_" + i;
      let symbolMarkup = svgMarkup
        .replaceAll("<svg", `<symbol id="${symbol_id}"`)
        .replaceAll("</svg>", `</symbol>`);
      svg.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", symbolMarkup);

      // create <use> element
      let use = document.createElementNS(ns, "use");
      copyAttributes(img, use, ["xlink:href"]);
      use.setAttribute("href", "#" + symbol_id);
      use.setAttributeNS(nsXlink, "xlink:href", "#" + symbol_id);

      // replace image with use
      img.replaceWith(use);
    }
    // if image contains raster/bitmap image
    else {
      // illustrator struggles with transform origins - better use transform matrix
      let mtx = img.getCTM()
      img.setAttribute('transform', `matrix(${mtx.a} ${mtx.b} ${mtx.c} ${mtx.d} ${mtx.e} ${mtx.f})`)
      img.removeAttribute('transform-origin')

      // get base64 data url
      let base64 = await blobToBase64(blob);
      img.setAttributeNS(nsXlink, "xlink:href", base64);
    }

    // add download link
    let markup = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
    let blobDownload = new Blob([markup], {
      type: "image/svg+xml"
    });
    aDownload.href = URL.createObjectURL(blobDownload);
  }

}

function copyAttributes(
  el,
  newEl,
  excludedAtts = [
    "d",
    "x",
    "y",
    "x1",
    "y1",
    "x2",
    "y2",
    "cx",
    "cy",
    "r",
    "rx",
    "ry",
    "points",
    "height",
    "width"
  ]
) {
  let atts = [...el.attributes];
  for (let a = 0; a < atts.length; a++) {
    let att = atts[a];
    if (excludedAtts.indexOf(att.nodeName) === -1) {
      let attrName = att.nodeName;
      let attrValue = att.nodeValue;
      newEl.setAttribute(attrName, attrValue + "");
    }
  }
}

function blobToBase64(blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.error = (err) => reject(err);
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
<image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5f/Red_X.svg/1024px-Red_X.svg.png" x="50" y="50" height="50" width="50" transform="rotate(45)" transform-origin="50 50"/>
<image xlink:href="https://placehold.co/50x50" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50"/>
</svg>
<p><a id="aDownload" href="" download="standalone.svg">Download svg</a></p>
```

Download links are blocked in SO snippet. See the [codepen example.](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/qBQgeBm)

It's safe to say, Adobe Illustrator has rather limited SVG support compared to modern browsers.

I also encountered a strange behavior: `<image>` elements with bitmap content  are not properly positioned in AI when preceded by a `<use>` element.

#### Improve backwards compatibility

- quite a lot of graphic applications still require the deprecated `xlink:href` attribute.
- I also highly recommend to add the `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  to the root svg element.
- add explicit `with` and `height` attributes as well as a `viewBox`
- inline styles might also cause issues (depending on the application's version) – prefer svg attributes (e.g `transform` instead of css transforms)
- AI also struggles with transform origins: you can instead apply a matrix transform and remove the transform origin property.